# Pass the value of a variable to a function in Python3

Tags: variables, python-3.x, return, parameter-passing

I have created a function that opens a file and reads the first line of it into a variable named 'farmer_id'. I would now like to use this 'farmer_id' variable in a second function in my script, and I'm not sure of the best way to do this. Global variables are allowed, so any solution is welcome.

I have read everything I can find on Stackoverflow on this topic, but I cannot find anything which works for my specific problem.

```
def get_id_from_file():
    file = open('C:/Users/my.name/Documents/test.txt', 'r')
    farmer_id = file.readline()
```

Comment: This is far too broad. Why can you not just do `my_function(farmer_id)`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The file contain a list of farmer_id? Do you want to use an iterator?

Comment: I tried my_function(farmer_id) but it throws the TypeError: 'missing one required positional argument'

Comment: So, what arguments does your function actually take? Maybe you should post it, so we can see.

Comment: @neo-blackcap: Yes it does, and any solution is welcome if it works

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I would have posted the entire script, but I'm not actually allowed to :/

Comment: Well at least post the function definition then.

Comment: That would be the entire script then :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
def any_func(former_id):
    pass

def get_id_from_file():
    file = open(r'C:/Users/my.name/Documents/test.txt', 'r')
    farmer_id = file.readline()
    return farmer_id

farmerid = get_id_from_file()
any_func(farmerid)
```